Segregate or identify each command interaction in Terminal.app?
The IntelliJ IDE by JetBrains will have a new Terminal window with the nifty feature of segregating each command-and-response. This feature makes visual scanning and re-reading much easier.

Is there any way to do this in the Terminal.app bundled with macOS?

You could define PS1 to include a horizontal line and some linefeeds.

Similar Question: How to draw a line between commands in zsh shell

And similar answer :-)
